# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out = Соединение с сервером закрыто?

Tags: java, сокет

Если задать сокету максимальное время ожидания получения данных 5 секунд

```
Socket ms = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
ms.setSoTimeout(5000);
```

то, при ошибке `SocketTimeoutException`

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

соединение с сервером закроется? То есть, сокет после такого исключения будет закрыт?

А если тайм-аут не устанавливать сокету, то такая ошибка вообще никогда не возникнет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)) не будет закрыт

> If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still valid.

\

> А если тайм-аут не устанавливать сокету, то такая ошибка вообще никогда не возникнет?

Да, будет ждать пока ОС не разорвет соединение.